# How to create VST plugin using MFC?

Tags: c++, audio, plugins, mfc, vst

I already have an MFC gui standalone program. What should be done to make it a VST 2.x plugin? (It would a lot of rework if I use VSTGUI/win32/qt/etc - or is it possible/appropriate to use VSTGUI?)

Which VST interfaces (gui and others) should I implement for VST 2.x gui plugin?

Comment: Is using WDL-OL a good way to go? There are no resource editors for it.

Answer (score 0):

You are worried about the GUI of a VST when in fact you should be worried about the structure of the rest of your code. VST 2.x hands you a HWND for a frame, all you have to do is create a child window that hosts your GUI. MFC, raw WIN32 - does not matter.

However, the real 'problem' is in the rest of the VST 2.x interface. You should study this interface and learn how it works. Then you'll be able to assess if your code is in the correct structure to easily interface as a VST plugin.

Comment: That's my second question: which interfaces (gui and others) should be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to slave your window code to the HWND you're given. The easiest way is just to slave your whole window using SetParent, and then implement MFC like you would in a normal app.

However, there are no knobs, nor digital or analog readouts. Even with MFC if you want to make a polished VST interface you'll be rolling your own UI code either way.

So it's *almost* worth it just to handle the WM_XXXX messages and do the windowing and drawing all yourself.